# При изменении элемента меню при наведении, блок изменяется на несколько пикселей, как это исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть вот такое меню. При наведении на элемент меню, должен появляться **border**. При появлении, он растягивает блок на несколько пикселей, как можно это исправить?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #FFCD00;
}

.header_top {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.header_top ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.header_top ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 54px 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #DA0000;
}

.menu_item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #DA0000;
}

.header_top > a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #DA0000;
}
.header_top > a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
        <header class="section-outer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header_top">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">

                    <ul class="main_menu">
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">EXPRESS</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">PARCEL & ECOMMERCE</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">LOGICTICS</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">MAIL</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">PRESS</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="#" class="search"><img src="img/search_icon.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </header>
```

Comment: вы сделайте так - border 4px solid transparent а при наведении   border 4px solid red тогда скакать не будет

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так. Я классу `.section-outer` присвоил высоту.

```css
.section-outer{height:130px;}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #FFCD00;
}

.header_top {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
          overflow:hidden;
     }
.header_top ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.header_top ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 54px 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #DA0000;
}

.menu_item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #DA0000;overflow:hidden;
}

.header_top > a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #DA0000;
}
.header_top > a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="section-outer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header_top">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">

                    <ul class="main_menu">
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">EXPRESS</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">PARCEL & ECOMMERCE</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">LOGICTICS</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">MAIL</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">PRESS</a></li>
                        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="#" class="search"><img src="img/search_icon.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </header>
```